# How to read content from links and save results for each page as txt-File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in Python. I have a CSV-File with links of webpages. First I'd like to read this file and find for each webpage all further links. Then I'd like to read the content from this links and save all content from a webpage to a txt-file. I need for each Webpage a txt-file. My problem now is, that I didn't get some results.

I use Python 3 and work with Anaconda.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#1. Read csv-file with list of webpages

with open('F:\Promotion\CSV\Liste_Blogs_Test.csv','r') as csvf:
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)

#2. Read links
    for url in urls:  # Parse through each url in the list.
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        #print(soup)
#3. Find for all Websites all other links
        for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            webpage_links = [link['href']]
            #print(webpage_links)
#4. Read content of links and save it to txt for the website
            for x in webpage_links:
                try:
                    with open('{}.txt' % url, 'a') as f:    
                        link_content = urlopen(x[0]).read()
                        soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(link_content,"html.parser")
                        soup_1.prettify()
                        print(soup_1)
                        for a in soup_1.find_all('p'):
                            print(test.get_text())
                            content = a.get_text()
                            print(content)
                            f.write(content % url)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

Comment: You don't have any output at all? Maybe try to not silently swallow the error:
`except ValueError as e: print(e)`

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Now I get for e: 'unknown url type: 'h'. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error points you in the right direction: the URL you are trying to load is `"h"`, which is obviously an invalid URL. I see you are doing `urlopen(x[0]).read()`. Why `x[0]`? `x` should be your full URL, if you do `x[0]`, you are taking the first character, the "h" of "http://...".